# When trying to add a listener to textview added programmatically only the last one works as intended

Tags: android

After a consumption of a webservice, i got an json object, after the parse i need to create a textview (for each element) and to each of them add a listener.
currently ALL TEXTVIEW get binded with the same ID (the last one) so they all pass the same extra (in this case id_asignacion)

Here the code that adds the textviews and binds them with a listener:

```
    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    descripcion = oneObject.getString("descripcion");
                    direccion = oneObject.getString("direccion");
                    id_denuncia = oneObject.getString("idDenuncia");
                    TextView nueva_asignacion = new TextView(ctx);
                    ImageView separador = new ImageView(ctx);
                    separador.setImageResource(R.drawable.barrablanca);
                    nueva_asignacion.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris_claro));
                    nueva_asignacion.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dpde10));
                    if(int_color == 0){
                        nueva_asignacion.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
                        int_color = 1;
                    }else{
                        nueva_asignacion.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris_perfil));
                        int_color = 0;
                    }
                    nueva_asignacion.setText(descripcion + ".\nEn: " + direccion);
                    linearLayout_asignaciones.addView(nueva_asignacion);
                    nueva_asignacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            abrir_detalle_asignacion(id_denuncia);
                        }
                        });

                    linearLayout_asignaciones.addView(separador);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

The function that i bind them to (abrir_detalle_asignacion ) its the following:

```
    public void abrir_detalle_asignacion(String id_denuncia) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, DetalleAsignacion.class);
        intent.putExtra("RUT", RutLog);
        intent.putExtra("id_inspector", id_inspector);
        intent.putExtra("id_asignacion", id_denuncia);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);
    }
```

TL DR: Every Textview is Binded with the SAME id_denuncia, So all the Textviews do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem with id_denuncia , because you override it's value on every iteration and the last value is actually passed on every click, and that's why only the last TextView works as expected

There are several solutions, for example
pass the string from the json by index, something like -

```
abrir_detalle_asignacion(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("idDenuncia"));
```

OR

Maybe store the values in an array, and pass the value from the array by index to the method:

```
abrir_detalle_asignacion(id_denuncia_array[i]);
```

Comment: ill give it a try and if it works ill pray for you every night in the following month.

Comment: ITS WORKS!!, just had to modify your answer a little, add try catch and cast FINAL to the int. Thanks!

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare own class

```
class MyOnClick implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final String id;
    MyOnClick(String s) {
        id = new String(s);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        abrir_detalle_asignacion(id);
    }
}
```

and use it: `nueva_asignacion.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClick(id_denuncia))`